# Require file extension in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is redirecting `mywebsite.com/news` to `mywebsite.com/news.php` but I don't want it.
I need it to redirect `mywebsite.com/news` to `mywebsite.com/index.php?param=news`
I changed my `.htaccess` file and the file does work correctly for other words, like this:
`mywebsite.com/hello` redirects to: `mywebsite.com/index.php?param=hello`
I have a `news.php` file in my root folder, but I don't want `mywebsite.com/news` to redirect to `mywebsite.com/news.php`
I hope you understand what I mean...
This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes

# pass the default character set
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([\s\S]+)$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA,NC,NE]
```

What changes should I make to solve this?
Any helps, comments, suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Options` line to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a
>   request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and
>   /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory
>   looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map
>   which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and
>   content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of
>   them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's
>   requirements.
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

You also can remove .php extension with:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. :) Works as expected!